# Initializing an Object on the Server

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I've succesfully implimented a simple remoting setup where a client is able to obtain an instance of an object and call individial methods over the process boundary. My problem is that i need to set a value at the server then have this avalible over the remoting call in the client/s. The exact required process flow is as follows:

1. Server application is started with commanline line arguments.
2. The listening server is started.
3. Server starts client application
4. Client creates an instance of a server object with remoting which should contain the commanline arguments (strings) which the Server was started with.

Is there a good way of doing this? Bear in mind that this is the only structure that works here as calling the client with arguments directly isn't possible, the call needs to come from the server which is the one which can receive the commandline args.

Further Info: I want to avoid saving data to a file etc and then using a method in the initialised server class to read that file, ideal would be to create an instance of the class on the server then have that instance avaliable to the clients, i don't belive this is possible though?

Comment: Is remoting a requirement?  Why not use WCF?  Much better security model and easier to work with.

Comment: No need for security here, just a more elgant way over exchanging data than throwing it all in an INI file (the current method) and having it read at the client.

Comment: "No need for security" ... famous last words.  FYI, the last several Windows attacks were based on DCOM which is pretty much the same thing as .Net Remoting.

Comment: Remoting was essentially abandoned over 10 years ago. It was fully replaced by WCF.

Comment: @MatthewWhited DCOM was *not* the same as .NET Remoting, in fact, back when Remoting was actually in use, Enterprise Services (aka COM+) were required to provide advanced services like instance management, transactions, security. Remoting had none. WCF was no harder than Remoting to configure (it's not easier either) but offered all of the services.

Comment: @MatthewWhited can't remember using Remoting in the last 12-13 years.

Comment: @DanHall let's put aside that Remoting was abandoned essentially in 2005. Why do you think a remote settings service is *more elegant* than replicated settings? Or a database? Or using the manageability and replication mechanisms provided by Windows, like group policies, DSC ? Or even a *file share*?

Comment: I didn't they they were the same, I said they were pretty much the same. (Remoting uses similar security vectors as DCOM) My point of WCF being easier isn't in the configuration side (that can be a pain).  It's on development, maintenance, security, protocols and pretty much everything else.  Either way... Use WCF or WebAPI not remoting.

Comment: @MatthewWhited quite possibly. DCOM was before my time: I picked up COM+ in 2001 which was quite a bit more advanced :P.

Comment: Long story short, use services and not rpc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your comment but you have taken a lot of liberty in guessing the intended use. I need to pass one small string between application A and B, the programming overhead for the Remoting setup was tiny! I was just after a better way of passing the value which is pushed to the server and not pulled by it. Be it legacy or not you don't need a tank to do the work of a 2cv, especially if the load isn't ever going to change!

Comment: @MatthewWhited i did say the previous data was provided over a INI file... nothing about this particular system is sensitive hence the lack of caution.

Comment: @DanHall I didn't take any liberties. I've seen this already. And using a deprecated (as in obsolete, not really supported, not to be used) service just to write something to a database or queue, isn't the greatest idea. Plus, there *are* ready-made solutions for this, either as OS services (Event log can *push* or *pull* events from multiple events into a central one), RabbitMQ, or just a database. Even an in-memory one.